# Firebase & Cloud Audit Logs event in custom region

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have the following code in VC

```
    const {onCustomEventPublished} = require("firebase-functions/v2/eventarc");
    exports.predictionAuditLogMonitor2 = onCustomEventPublished(
        {
          eventType: "google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written",
          filters: {
            "serviceName": "bigquery.googleapis.com",
            "methodName": "google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob",
          },
          region: "europe-west1",
        },
        (event) => {
           logger.info("Received cloud audit log", event);
        },
    );
```

I understand that, when using standard channels, the function should not be created with custom attributes.

However, when I create the function as follows:

```
    const {onCustomEventPublished} = require("firebase-functions/v2/eventarc");
    exports.predictionAuditLogMonitor2 = onCustomEventPublished(
        "google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written",
        (event) => {
          logger.info("Received cloud audit log", event);
        },
    );
```

then it gets created in us-east1 region.

What would be the appropriate way to create the function via code, but still to get the function created in europe-west1 region?